Comparing retrospective and prospective cohorts
I am a bit confused on comparing retrospective and prospective cohorts …
Say I have two cohorts, one retrospective (used as the control) and one prospective cohort (with a program/intervention applied). Can I use regular statistic tests, such as chi-square, CMH, etc., to compare various characteristics between the two cohorts (e.g., number of deaths)? Not too sure if I need "special" tests …

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
